# A problem occurred configuring project ':app' ionic

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm traying to run mi app in my phone, i do the command "ionic corodva run android" and when it arrives in the part to build the apk it fails

I`m using:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.7.1 (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10

the problem happens here:

> cordova run android
>   Android Studio project detected
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
>   studio
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>   publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses (C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts-remapped\build_whhgwacyeywmiczoleie675g\dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses\cp_proj4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f).
  >   Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\GitHub\Camaleon-Movil\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts\dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses\cp_proj\cp_proj4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f).
  >   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts\dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses\cp_proj\cp_proj4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses (C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts-remapped\build_whhgwacyeywmiczoleie675g\dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses\cp_proj4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f).
  >   Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\GitHub\Camaleon-Movil\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts\dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses\cp_proj\cp_proj4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f).
  >   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\4.1\scripts\dr0b9ko67krk4zdc7kn2nhses\cp_proj\cp_proj4dada6424967ba8dfea75e81c8880f7f\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova run android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I expect that te application runs in my phone, but with this problem the apk couldn't be creates

Comment: Try installing the compatible version of android sdk from android studio.